# creating dropdown login bar... except swing to the left instead of right

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Okay, this is a little tricky to describe, but I think best described by these examples on other sites.

I'm trying to create a 'login' menu that drops down, similar to here:
www.dropbox.com
Notice how it swings to the left (or in other words, the right side is continuous)

However, my site keeps looking like this:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/
Notice on it swings to the right (or in other words, the left side is continuous)

Is there a direction you all could point me at? I've searched within CSS, but with no luck.. Thanks, Matt

Comment: I am getting page not found here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/

Comment: drupality, thanks for looking into this. The link works, just takes forever to load for some reason. Dirk (below) was able to help. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving the dropped down element an 'absolute' positioning. Then set the 'right' property to 0px.

```
#droppedElement {
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
}
```

You might have to adjust some more properties, like 'top', 'margin' or 'padding', but that depends of course on your layout, which I can't see.

Comment: Awesome! You don't know how long I've been playing with this.. Thanks Dirk.